# Query returns results from yesterday's database (It's like the X-files but for data)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am seeing something in Python which is absolutely blowing my mind!

When i run the following script i get results which don't match what is in the database:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=example;Description=example;UID=example;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=example;Database = example')
cursor = conn.cursor()

QS = """select
                    cct.product_group,
                    cct.website,
                    SUM(cct.sales_value) as sales,
                    SUM(cct.sales_value) - SUM(cct.cogs) +  SUM(cct.carriage_reclaim) - SUM(cct.carriage_costs) - SUM(cct.carriage_costs_estimate) - SUM(cct.metapack_costs) - SUM(cct.mktg_costs) - SUM(cct.mktg_costs_estimate) - SUM(cct.finance_costs) - SUM(cct.royalty) - SUM(cct.scrap_costs) as cavo,
                    sum(cct.budget_sales_value) as budget_sales,
                    sum(cct.budget_sales_phased) as budget_sales_phased,
                    sum(budget_sales_value - budget_cogs + budget_carriage_reclaim - budget_carriage_costs - budget_metapack_costs - budget_mktg_costs - budget_affiliate_costs - budget_offline_costs - budget_royalty - budget_finance_costs - budget_scrap_costs) as budget_cavo
                from
                        Phocas_TG.dbo.cavo_cube_trans cct
                    where
                        cct.date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-01'
                    and
                        cct.product_group in ('BATH', 'HEAT', 'SOLA')
                group by
                    cct.product_group,
                    cct.website
                """

cursor.execute(QS)

row = 1

while row:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row
```

results (wrong):

```
(u'SOLA', u'Beam LED', 0.0, 0.0, 162742.97946200587, 0.0, 18193.81407224502)
(u'BATH', u'Best Bathrooms', 0.0, 0.0, 41916.63833219, 0.0, 8616.793372278)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Bathrooms', 0.0, 0.0, 6608.969775007, 0.0, 2156.7834558070012)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Heating', 0.0, 0.0, 1221384.659527106, 0.0, 377841.5168052811)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Heating DE', 0.0, 0.0, 29173.095597537005, 0.0, 8475.738008001004)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Heating IE', 0.0, 0.0, 22200.070480626007, 0.0, 7635.299995903)
(u'BATH', u'Big Bathroom Shop', 0.0, 0.0, 194083.00040568004, 0.0, 24954.13424082598)
(u'HEAT', u'Big Bathroom Shop', 0.0, 0.0, 22149.000000066, 0.0, 8705.787840001001)
(u'SOLA', u'Big Bathroom Shop', 0.0, 0.0, 5100.480000258, 0.0, 1083.4538447940001)
(u'BATH', u'Cheap Suites', 0.0, 0.0, 96801.99990245397, 0.0, 14238.596937037)
(u'HEAT', u'Cheap Suites', 0.0, 0.0, 106569.44176593704, 0.0, 33754.97526726799)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed CA', 0.0, 0.0, 37082.100495228, 0.0, 12856.460342323007)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed CA', 0.0, 0.0, 9353.568286208001, 0.0, 880.9490233900004)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed DE', 0.0, 0.0, 101559.039541116, 0.0, 23292.634339761993)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed DE', 0.0, 0.0, 113215.76626921304, 0.0, 36837.99376355698)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed DE', 0.0, 0.0, 4854.377637117, 0.0, 1737.9875217079998)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed ES', 0.0, 0.0, 19604.31999891699, 0.0, 4734.427979470002)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed ES', 0.0, 0.0, 34249.141983546, 0.0, 10209.710455291004)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed ES', 0.0, 0.0, 289.80000006, 0.0, 116.75621339399999)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed FR', 0.0, 0.0, 347181.18108432164, 0.0, 69657.60552098301)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed FR', 0.0, 0.0, 226974.89734840707, 0.0, 66110.17134250299)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed FR', 0.0, 0.0, 4854.377637116998, 0.0, 1737.7115216809996)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed IT', 0.0, 0.0, 16166.474983498987, 0.0, 3377.9398536559997)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed IT', 0.0, 0.0, 44038.997226871994, 0.0, 10705.928342997002)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed IT', 0.0, 0.0, 289.80000006, 0.0, 116.75621339399996)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed NL', 0.0, 0.0, 109605.65601838099, 0.0, 21186.901077737002)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed NL', 0.0, 0.0, 111566.249953006, 0.0, 25728.021958158002)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed NL', 0.0, 0.0, 289.80000006, 0.0, 116.75621338999997)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed US', 0.0, 0.0, 183865.59700310798, 0.0, 71254.06636748096)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed US', 0.0, 0.0, 45660.18595451701, 0.0, 14384.518580477998)
(u'BATH', u'Trueshopping', 0.0, 0.0, 79736.07721019002, 0.0, 17654.34511784)
(u'HEAT', u'Trueshopping', 0.0, 0.0, 74418.77915825398, 0.0, 21116.580455338993)
None
```

However, if i run the SAME script, but ever-so-slightly change the sql string (add a tiny bit of whitespace to one of the lines) i get the correct results:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=example;Description=example;UID=example;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=example;Database = example')
cursor = conn.cursor()

QS = """select
                     cct.product_group,
                    cct.website,
                    SUM(cct.sales_value) as sales,
                    SUM(cct.sales_value) - SUM(cct.cogs) +  SUM(cct.carriage_reclaim) - SUM(cct.carriage_costs) - SUM(cct.carriage_costs_estimate) - SUM(cct.metapack_costs) - SUM(cct.mktg_costs) - SUM(cct.mktg_costs_estimate) - SUM(cct.finance_costs) - SUM(cct.royalty) - SUM(cct.scrap_costs) as cavo,
                    sum(cct.budget_sales_value) as budget_sales,
                    sum(cct.budget_sales_phased) as budget_sales_phased,
                    sum(budget_sales_value - budget_cogs + budget_carriage_reclaim - budget_carriage_costs - budget_metapack_costs - budget_mktg_costs - budget_affiliate_costs - budget_offline_costs - budget_royalty - budget_finance_costs - budget_scrap_costs) as budget_cavo
                from
                        Phocas_TG.dbo.cavo_cube_trans cct
                    where
                        cct.date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-01'
                    and
                        cct.product_group in ('BATH', 'HEAT', 'SOLA')
                group by
                    cct.product_group,
                    cct.website
                """

cursor.execute(QS)

row = 1

while row:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row
```

results (Correct):

```
(u'SOLA', u'Beam LED', 5065.771499999995, 96.61683876775501, 162742.97946200587, 10194.260000000007, 18193.814072245008)
(u'BATH', u'Best Bathrooms', 2953.044100000001, 92.97357616908354, 41916.63833219, 2635.92, 8616.793372277998)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Bathrooms', 714.1080000000002, 242.6900400000002, 6608.969775007001, 411.96000000000004, 2156.7834558070003)
(u'SOLA', u'Best Eco Shop', 476.55, 90.5512, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Heating', 67855.21000000008, 20803.223713668747, 1221384.6595271053, 75820.06999999998, 377841.516805281)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Heating DE', 764.414853, -74.59615568499949, 29173.095597537005, 1804.9900000000002, 8475.738008001008)
(u'HEAT', u'Best Heating IE', 511.684638, 145.72208938499998, 22200.070480626004, 1384.869999999999, 7635.299995903002)
(u'BATH', u'Beste Badezimmer', 605.427752, 136.0132520000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(u'BATH', u'Big Bathroom Shop', 9055.997500000003, 1090.7121487611153, 194083.00040568007, 12434.420000000002, 24954.134240825995)
(u'HEAT', u'Big Bathroom Shop', 1637.3744000000004, 624.0700689273556, 22149.000000066, 1391.72, 8705.787840001)
(u'SOLA', u'Big Bathroom Shop', 0.0, 0.0, 5100.480000257999, 319.48999999999995, 1083.453844794)
(u'BATH', u'Cheap Suites', 6708.027599999998, 1218.3929213940442, 96801.99990245402, 6082.849999999999, 14238.596937036995)
(u'HEAT', u'Cheap Suites', 7877.586600000003, 3094.981148824446, 106569.44176593701, 6610.709999999997, 33754.975267268004)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed CA', 2450.690545, 520.74435478, 37082.100495228, 2355.16, 12856.460342323011)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed CA', 198.955982, 43.108281999999996, 9353.568286207998, 593.02, 880.94902339)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed DE', 7626.790740999998, 1737.584896192042, 101559.039541116, 6444.300000000002, 23292.634339761993)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed DE', 10397.459475000007, 3731.6650875108417, 113215.76626921303, 7008.19, 36837.993763557)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed DE', 0.0, 0.0, 4854.377637117, 304.08000000000004, 1737.9875217079998)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed ES', 2748.9035340000005, 965.6333561828495, 19604.319998916995, 1216.6799999999998, 4734.42797947)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed ES', 1702.1610810000002, 589.3538634675374, 34249.141983546, 2118.4200000000005, 10209.710455291004)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed ES', 0.0, 0.0, 289.80000006, 18.16, 116.75621339399999)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed FR', 47273.83856200002, 14384.879203607652, 347181.18108432164, 21603.31999999999, 69657.60552098295)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed FR', 19740.58251500001, 6704.351543201098, 226974.89734840702, 13947.230000000001, 66110.171342503)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed FR', 0.0, 0.0, 4854.377637116998, 304.08000000000004, 1737.7115216809996)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed IT', 1520.260361, 221.10746836602254, 16166.474983499003, 1003.3399999999998, 3377.939853656)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed IT', 3123.910959, 667.0734018041572, 44038.997226871994, 2706.38, 10705.928342997002)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed IT', 0.0, 0.0, 289.80000005999995, 18.16, 116.75621339399997)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed NL', 16583.111918, 5610.879630999159, 109605.65601838099, 6872.79, 21186.901077737002)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed NL', 10411.469125, 3712.277327632342, 111566.249953006, 6818.089999999997, 25728.021958158024)
(u'SOLA', u'Hudson Reed NL', 0.0, 0.0, 289.80000006, 18.16, 116.75621338999997)
(u'BATH', u'Hudson Reed US', 8481.261439000004, 3675.9046331535123, 183865.59700310792, 11516.219999999996, 71254.06636748099)
(u'HEAT', u'Hudson Reed US', 2097.8916030000005, 938.4614114663307, 45660.18595451701, 2833.7799999999993, 14384.518580478)
(u'BATH', u'Trueshopping', 5265.242654999999, 583.9883320369803, 79736.07721019002, 5047.579999999999, 17654.345117839996)
(u'HEAT', u'Trueshopping', 5519.389900000001, 1508.0805920000003, 74418.77915825396, 4634.490000000001, 21116.580455338986)
(u'SOLA', u'Trueshopping', 777.320599, 268.97614415250007, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
None
```

If it helps, the database is essentially a data cube which gets rebuilt every night. The results of the first query seem to match the database from yesterday - Could this be some sort of cache system? Where results are stored for queries which have already been run?

I'm SO confused! Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Huh? I don't understand the question to be honest. Why not make this a stored proc instead of pass though sql? Also, why bother with between two dates when the two dates are identical? There is no value value other than 2016-02-01 that would work there. A simple equality would make more sense.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, The Question is more about understanding the reason this happens rather than evaluating my code thanks. In the production script i run, the two dates are variable and are passed by string formatting. The results are then used to generate a report which is emailed. I was getting unexpected results, i isolated the problem and posted it here.

Comment: I had a feeling they were variables which brings up the question of sql injection. The challenge is we can't see your tables or execute this without quite a bit of effort. What are describing does not sound possible but obviously if you can recreate it then something is happening.

Comment: Indeed, i get the same wrong results every time i run the first query and the same correct results every time i run the second query. The only difference being i've added a space at the start of the second line in the second query. It MUST be to do with the results for previous queries being stored in some sort of cache, but i know very little about this unfortunately.

Comment: Query results do not get stored in a cache. The execution plan gets stored in cache but not the actual results. Why not toss this into a procedure? It would give you separation between the visual and data layers. In addition I suspect this problem would fix itself when you start using procedures.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces somewhere in the query? That can cause Python 3 to do odd things. Also, I'd advice against stored procedures with pyodbc, as several features (such as OUTPUT variables) are not supported, and it must be called with T-SQL's EXEC through a cursor.execute() anyway.